# Flex Property - Restart the row

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a fieldcontainer which has several components. Each components has `flex` property as well. What I want to know that how can we **break the row**? As you can see the screen shot, 'FREE ARTICLE' field should start beginning of the new row but I don't know how can I specify this.

[image]

```
    items: new Ext.Panel({
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Artikel Sorgulama',
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },
            height: '86px',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'articleNo',
                            flex: 1,
                            tabIndex: 1,
                            fieldLabel: 'ARTİKEL NO',
                            fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 12pt',
                            margins: '0 10 0 0',
                            enableKeyEvents: true,
                            listeners: {
                                specialkey: function (field, e) {
                                    if (field.getValue() != 'null') {

                                        if (e.getKey() === e.ENTER || e.TAB) {
                                            //articles.proxy.extraParams = {'article': field.getValue()};
                                            articles.load({
                                                params: {'article': field.getValue()},
                                                callback: function () {
                                                    Ext.getCmp('articleDesc').setValue(articles.data.items[0].data['ART_DESC']);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                focus: function (e) {
                                    e.setValue('');
                                    Ext.getCmp('articleDesc').setValue("");
                                    articles.loadData([], false);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            id: 'articleDesc',
                            flex: 3,
                            fieldLabel: 'ARTİKEL TANIMI',
                            fieldStyle: 'font-size: 12pt',
                            readOnly: true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'FREE ARTICLE',
                            flex: 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't add your free article field to the field container, but to the parent fieldset instead:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        // ...
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                layout: 'hbox',
                // ...
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'FREE ARTICLE'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you rixo, much appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use nested box layouts. The field container have a `vbox` layout. The first item in the `fieldcontainer` should be a `container` with an `hbox` layout (like your current code). The second item of the `fieldcontainer` should be the 3rd field (which will appear underneath due to the `vbox` layout).